# Why are the buttons not going to the next activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclicklistener, start-activity

For some reason my buttons aren't doing anything. I've used this method to implement buttons before and it never gave me an issue. The app has seven different buttons that all move to a different activity.

```
public class ScheduleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button mondayButton,tuesdayButton,wednesdayButton,thursdayButton,fridayButton,saturdayButton,sundayButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);
        mondayButton = findViewById(R.id.monday_button);
        tuesdayButton = findViewById(R.id.tuesday_button);
        wednesdayButton = findViewById(R.id.wednesday_button);
        thursdayButton = findViewById(R.id.thursday_button);
        fridayButton = findViewById(R.id.friday_button);
        saturdayButton = findViewById(R.id.saturday_button);
        sundayButton = findViewById(R.id.sunday_button);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.monday_button:
                Intent monday_intent = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, MondayActivity.class);
                startActivity(monday_intent);
                break;
            case R.id.tuesday_button:
                Intent tuesday_intent = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, TuesdayActivity.class);
                startActivity(tuesday_intent);
                break;
            case R.id.wednesday_button:
                Intent wednesday_intent = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, WednesdayActivity.class);
                startActivity(wednesday_intent);
                break;
            case R.id.thursday_button:
                Intent thursday_intent = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, ThursdayActivity.class);
                startActivity(thursday_intent);
                break;
            case R.id.friday_button:
                Intent friday_intent = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, FridayActivity.class);
                startActivity(friday_intent);
                break;
            case R.id.saturday_button:
                Intent saturday_intent = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, SaturdayActivity.class);
                startActivity(saturday_intent);
            case R.id.sunday_button:
                Intent sunday_intent = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, SundayActivity.class);
                startActivity(sunday_intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the instances of the buttons but never setting an OnClickListener for them. You need to set the click listener for the buttons:

```java
mondayButton.setOnClickListener(this)
```

You need to do this to all buttons, this tells your code where to notify the event when the button is clicked.

Comment: Can you please show me an example of where I would put that in my code?

Comment: Just put it after you call the findViewById for all the buttons

Answer (score 1):

you are not attaching the listener `View.OnClickListener` to any of your buttons.
add this in your `onCreate()` after you init your buttons, your buttons will work

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);
        ...
        sundayButton = findViewById(R.id.sunday_button);

        // attaching listeners
        mondayButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        tuesdayButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        wednesdayButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        thursdayButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        fridayButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        saturdayButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        sundayButton.setOnClickListener(this);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the view.setOnClickListener{} on the OnCreate method

private Button mondayButton,tuesdayButton,wednesdayButton,thursdayButton,fridayButton,saturdayButton,sundayButton;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);
    mondayButton = findViewById(R.id.monday_button);
    tuesdayButton = findViewById(R.id.tuesday_button);
    wednesdayButton = findViewById(R.id.wednesday_button);
    thursdayButton = findViewById(R.id.thursday_button);
    fridayButton = findViewById(R.id.friday_button);
    saturdayButton = findViewById(R.id.saturday_button);
    sundayButton = findViewById(R.id.sunday_button);


    mondayButton.setOnClickListener() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(...) ;
    startActivity(intent) ;
   } 
}
```